When does the rank of a tensor reduce when we integrate it over a 3D foliation of spacetime?
In physics, we have the idea that the integral over $d^3x$ of the 0th component of energy-momentum density $T^{\mu \nu}$:
$P^{\mu}=\int d^3x T^{\mu 0}$
transforms like a Lorentz four-vector.
Similarly, the integral of the 0th component of the electric current $J^{\mu}$, over a 3D foliation of spacetime,:
$Q=\int d^3x J^0 $
transforms like a Lorentz scalar
In both cases, we have a tensor $T^{\mu \nu}$ and $J^{\mu}$, we set one of the indices to 0, then integrate it over a 3D foliation of the manifold, and what we get is a quantity that transforms like a tensor whose rank is one lower than the tensor we started with. What exactly is happening here in mathematical terms?
What is the most mathematically generalised version of this idea? Does this idea hold for arbitrary tensor fields or only for tensor fields obeying a continuity equation?
Are these tensor-like things that we obtained tensors under general co ordinate transformations or only under Lorentz transforms?
Usually, I think of tensors as attached to a single point of a manifold. But here, we have got a sort-of "global" tensor quantity, which has been obtained by an integral over a foliation of the manifold, which is why I think it's strange. Also, usually, the tensors that we can integrate are differential forms but we're integrating contravariant tensors here

Let us consider the case of the stress energy tensor field $T_{\mu\nu}(x)$ in Minkowski spacetime $M^4$.  Let $v$ be a constant  co-vector. Since $\partial_\mu (T^{\mu\nu} v_\nu) = (\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}) v_\nu =  0$ we can can use the divergence theorem to prove that, if $T^{\mu\nu}$ decays suffuciently rapidly at spacelike infinity (*),
$$\int_\Sigma T^{\mu\nu}v_\nu n^{(\Sigma)}_\mu d^3x = \int_{\Sigma'} T^{\mu\nu}v_\nu n^{(\Sigma')}_\mu d^3x\tag{1} $$
for every choice of spatial rest spaces $\Sigma, \Sigma'$ of (generally different) Minkowski reference frames, where $n^{(\Sigma)}$ denotes the unit normal vector to $\Sigma$.
Eq.(1) proves  that the linear map $$ V^4\ni v \mapsto \int_\Sigma T^{\mu\nu}v_\nu n^{(\Sigma)}_\mu d^3x $$
is well defined,
where $V^4$ is the vector space of translations in $M^4$. This map does not depend on the choice of $\Sigma$. Every linear map on contravariant vectors defines a covariant vector. Therefore, there is a well defined $P\in (V^4)^*$ such that
$$\langle P, v\rangle = P_\nu v^\nu =  \int_\Sigma T^{\mu\nu}v_\nu n^{(\Sigma)}_\mu d^3x \:.$$
In other words,
$$P_\nu :=  \int_\Sigma T^{\mu\nu} n^{(\Sigma)}_\mu d^3x$$
is a well defined covariant four vector, the total four momentum of the system, independently from the choice of $\Sigma$.
This procedure, in Minkowski spacetime, is general: if you have a tensor field $T^{\mu\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}(x)$ of order $n+1$ satisfying a conservation rule
$$\partial_\mu T^{\mu\mu_2\cdots \mu_n}=0\:,$$
then, provided it decreases sufficiently rapidly at spatial infinity,
$$Z^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n} := \int_\Sigma T^{\mu\mu_1\ldots \mu_n} n^{(\Sigma)}_\mu d^3x$$
is a well defined tensor  of order $n$.
Notice that we pass from tensor fields to tensors.
The crucial step is the fact that it makes sense to sum (integrate) tensors defined at different events on $\Sigma$.
It makes sense just because we are dealing with an affine space, where the spaces of tensors $(V^4)^{n\otimes}$ are well defined abstractly, without referring to events where they are applied. All this procedure cannot be used in curved spacetime (except for the case of a vector field, a current $J^\mu$, which gives rise to a scalar $Q$.).
Also sticking to Minkowski spacetime, it is clear that the procedure defined tensors and not tensor fields. Since they are not applied to a specific event it does not make sense to discuss if they are tensors with respect to general changes of coordinates, since the transformation matrix would depend on the place.
Another point is the relevance of the conservation law.  If the conservation law did not work, in principle, we could not have a well defined integral, since it could depend on the chosen spatial slice.
However, I am not sure that independence from the chosen flat integration slice is equivalent to a local conservation law.
(It is worth stressing that the spacelike Cauchy surface $\Sigma$ is allowed to be curved also in Minkowski spacetime without affecting the above result.)

(*) The proof of this fact is actually much more difficult than one expects at first glance. A rigorous proof of it can be readapted from the one of Proposition 37 in this paper recently published in Lett Math Phys by me and C. De Rosa.}

Thanks for the detailed answer. This means that the conservation law is sufficient to make this tensor well defined. Also, is my approach using generators completely incorrect? Or is it related to your answer ?(as in, maybe a less general version of your idea)

I think it is another possible approach, but it is valid only for the generators of Poincaré group, there are  more general tensors constructed out of integrations over spatial slices of conserved  tensor fields which do not depend on the Poincaré group.

This was my own question. I think I have traces of an answer.
First, I think these "global" tensors cannot be tensors under general diffeomorphisms, as the Jacobian of a general diffeomorphism varies with spacetime. So, in those cases, there can no "global" Jacobian transformation using which these global tensors can transform
Second, integrals of arbitrary tensor fields don't have this transformation behavior. We are not integrating generic tensor fields here. What we are specifically integrating is the energy-momentum density corresponding to a field configuration. This integral gives us the values of the energy-momentum generators. Now the translation generators of the Poincaire group transform like four vectors under Lorentz transforms. So the values of those generators, corresponding to a particular field configuration, also transform like four vectors under Lorentz transsforms
In summary, what I think we have here is a representation of the (Poincaire + Charge) generators on the space of field configurations. The generators in general have the alleged transformation behavior. The integrals simply give the values of those generators for a particular field configuration

Only the scalar case $Q$ makes sense in a generic spacetime. In the other cases, the tensors you consider make sense in Minkowski spacetime only just because it is an affine space (tensors are not attached  to specific points) and because the integrated tensorial currents satisfy a conservation law.

@ValterMoretti  i assumed the case where $Q$ commutes with everything else in the Lie Algebra. In general, I think these integrals wouldn't behave like tensors, as the Lie group generators can have non-tensorial transformation properties

@ValterMoretti i am not sure about the scope or correctness of this answer. Can you please write an answer about the general version of this idea on general spacetimes?
